# The order of direct and indirect object pronouns

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots

If we have both of them in a sentence, what's the order of them generally?
For example:

> Tu leur donnes des billets gratuits ?
>
> — Oui, je leur les donne.
>   **ou**
>   — Oui, je les leur donne.

Which answer is correct?

If we have also *en* and *y*, what's the order of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see a simple rule. Here are the possible combinations:

> Je *les* leur donne.  (Je donne *les bananes* aux singes)
>
> Je *les* y envoie.  (J'envoie *les lettres* à Paris)
>
> Je *les* en remercie.  (Je remercie *les lecteurs* de leur patience)
>
> Je leur *en* envoie.  (J'envoie *du secours* à ces messieurs)
>
> J'y *en* envoie.  (J'envoie *des schtroumpfs* sur la lune)

(Direct object pronouns are in italics).

Comment: I was once told the following rule, in order from closest to the verb moving towards the subject: (1) en (2) y (3) anything starting with L, in reverse alphabetic order (4) everything else. I dislike that this rule includes something so unscientific as "anything starting with L", but hey, it works and that's what counts for beginners. :)

Answer (score 4):

La règle générale est de mettre le complément d'objet direct premier avant les compléments indirects seconds. Quand les deux sont des pronoms personnels la régle est obligatoire.
Dans l'exemple que tu donnes on dit donc :

> Je les leur donne.

- Quand les compléments ne sont pas des pronoms on peut parfois avoir le complément d'objet indirect en premier.

> Elle indique au docteur son voisin.

(Sartre) exemple prit dans la *Grammaire Larousse du Français contemporain*.
Il s'agit du voisin du docteur. En disant :

> Elle indique son voisin au docteur.

Elle parlerait de son voisin à elle.

- Quand les deux groupes compléments sont de longueurs inégales on met de préférence le plus court en premier.

> J'ai indiqué à ces touristes le restaurant où nous avions si bien mangé la semaine dernière.
>
> ---

You might find [this](http://www.languageguide.org/french/grammar/pronouns/objects.html) about object pronouns and [this](http://www.languageguide.org/french/grammar/pronouns/object_order.html) about their order of some help. It will also help you with *y* and *en*.

Comment: La règle ne fonctionne pas avec « Je leur en donne ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Le cas de *en* et *y* sont, me semblait-il, traités dans la deuxième page à laquelle je renvoie sur le web.

Comment: Je n'étais pas d'accord avec « Quand les deux sont des pronoms personnels la règle est obligatoire ». Un autre exemple : « Je me les offre », le pronom COD vient en second là aussi.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez s'offrir est un verbe réflexif; je pense que c'est encore un cas différent.

Comment: @rds: Pas dans ce cas, « Je te les offre » si tu préfères.

Answer (score 4):

Quand on utilise deux pronoms compléments, on les place dans l'ordre suivant :

[image: ordre des pronoms en français]

Comment: @Gilles:I wrote it myself! I'm sure that this is useful.

Comment: À quoi sert donc la boîte avec y/en ? L'ordre habituellement décrit place *y* juste avant *en*.

Comment: L'ordre classique est décrit sur Wikipedia : [French Personal Pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_personal_pronouns#Clitic_order)