# How to replace two nouns with pronouns?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots, pronoms-personnels

For the sentence

> Jean va apporter des pralines à Marie

is this ok to write “Jean va lui apporter en” instead of “Jean va lui en apporter”?

I am facing this confusion as for the sentence

> Jean conseille quelques livres à Marie

“Jean lui en conseille” is the correct way to replace the nouns

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In affirmatives, except when preceded by a preposition¹, pronouns always come before the verb in French.

In “*Jean va apporter des pralines à Marie*”, “des pralines” is a direct object, “à Marie” is an indirect object, and both complement the verb *apporter*. Similar sentences that use pronouns include the following:

- *Jean va en apporter à Marie.*
- *Jean va lui apporter des pralines.*
- *Jean va lui en apporter.*

The same rules apply to verbs in the infinitive and to conjugated ones.

Here is a more complex sentence:

> Jean lui promet de lui en apporter.

In this sentence, the first *lui* stands for Marie as indirect object of *promettre*, the second *lui* also stands for Marie but as indirect object of *apporter*, and *en* stands for the pralines as direct object of *apporter*.

Also, the order of pronouns is fixed. Cf. [The order of direct and indirect object pronouns](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1738/the-order-of-direct-and-indirect-object-pronouns).

—
<sup>1. “Jean cueille ces fleurs pour Marie” becomes “Jean cueille ces fleurs pour elle”.</sup>

Answer (score -2):

Knowing that the addressee is Marie, and the gift a box of sugared almonds, you may say :

"Jean va lui en apporter", or :

"Jean va en apporter pour elle".

*But never end a sentence with "en".*

The construction of "Jean lui en conseille", when now you are speaking of books, is exactly the same.

*You may sometimes change the order* :

"J'en lui conseille" (but "Jean en" would be terrible for the ear).

"Louis en lui conseille" is better than "Louis lui en conseille" (for the same reason).

*Other examples* : "J'en lui sais gré", "J'en vous donne des exemples", rather classical but not obsolete, when you wish to insist on the indirect object and its proximity.

"Jean lui promet de lui en apporter" is not incorrect, but very inelegant, and suggests that the two "lui" are not standing for the same person. "Jean lui promet d'en apporter" is enough to guess that it's not for somebody else.

Comment: « *J'en lui conseille* », on ne doit probablement pas parler la même langue.

Comment: Peut-être, nous ne devons (et non "on ne doit") pas parler la même langue. Qu'il y a-t-il d'incorrect dans : -"Marie ne sait que choisir comme livres". - "J'en lui conseille". ?

Comment: Qu'y a-t-il (et non "Qu'il y a-til") d'incorrect dans *on ne doit* ?

Comment: *« J'en lui conseille »*, ça ne passe vraiment pas pour moi non plus. *« Je **lui en** conseille »*

Comment: Merci à Alexis Pigeon de m'avoir souligné une négligence : j'en lui sais gré. Ma critique du "on ne doit" ? J'en vous explique la raison : "nous" désigne deux personnes ou plus, ce qui est le cas ; "on" l'homme en général, et "on ne doit pas parler la même langue", à la rigueur, signifierait que chacun doit avoir la sienne. J'ai récidivé quant à la construction "j'en + pronom complément + verbe", vous choque-elle toujours ? J'ignore quelle règle s'y opposerait.

Comment: En plus du fait que "j'en lui" semble incorrect, à l'oral on comprendra "jean lui".

Comment: "On" peut tout à fait désigner le locuteur et son interlocuteur, et uniquement eux. "On va prendre un verre" n'a jamais signifié que l'ensemble du genre humain était invité à savourer une mousse au bar du coin. Et pour ce qui est de tes nouveaux exemples, oui, ils me choquent toujours. On dirait des tentatives ratées (car incorrectes) de parler d'une manière pompeuse. Cela rend le discours dur à comprendre, presque pénible car il nécessite un effort pour remettre les mots à leur place habituelle.

Comment: @MarkThorin petite note au passage : pense à ajouter `@<pseudo>` en début de commentaire si tu veux répondre à quelqu'un, ainsi ton interlocuteur recevra une notification.

Comment: @Alexis Pigeon Merci; nouveau, je sais mal me servir des outils; j'ai essayé, mais c'était supprimé du texte - par quelle fausse-manœuvre? Inversement, je n'ai jamais reçu aucune notification, il me faut rappeller une intervention, ce que je ne fais que si j'ai été pénalisé. Je maintiens que le "on" à la place du "nous" est une faute, quoique très courante, qu'un bon auteur ne fait pas. Quant aux exemples, que j'ai ajoutés, ils me semblent être une nuance de style dont il serait dommage de se priver, à moins qu'une règle grammaticale ne l'interdise - j'attends avec impatience une référence.

Comment: Il y a sûrement une règle grammaticale, mais tu pourrais aussi vérifier l'usage. « [J'en lui sais gré](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22J'en+lui+sais+gr%C3%A9%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) », ce n'est même pas une erreur quelquefois commise : tu es le premier à l'avoir écrit sur le web.

Comment: @MarkThorin "on", [sens 3 du Littré](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/on) : *On, désignant en général les hommes, les gens, peut, selon la signification du discours, restreindre son sens à telle ou telle personne désignée par je, tu, il, nous, vous, ils.* Idem pour le [sens 2 du Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/on#Pronom_personnel), ou le [5 du Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/on/55984?q=on#55628).

Comment: @Alexis Pigeon Bien entendu ! Le contexte est limitatif, mais l'indéfinition demeure, par ignorance ou volonté de généralité. "On a beaucoup discuté de ma réponse, peut-être plus qu'elle ne le méritait." : je n'imagine pas qu'il s'agisse de toute l'humanité, mais d'un groupe indéfini. "Qu'on évacue le prétoire!" : le Président ne sait ni les noms, ni le nombre des présents, et s'adresse en général à eux et aux gardes. Ce que je conteste, c'est l'emploi de "on" lorsqu'un locuteur précis écrit à un seul interlocuteur connu. Votre réponse est utile, on vous a mis un point de plus (devinez qui).

Comment: @Gilles Que l'on me montre cette règle, ou du moins démontre l'illogisme de la construction ! Les nombreux locuteurs - surtout provinciaux, ce qui ne signifie pas illettrés - que j'ai entendus seront ravis que la tournure soit maintenant consacrée sur Internet. ;-)

Comment: @MarkThorin Jamais tu ne demanderais "on y va?" à une personne en particulier?

Comment: Pourquoi on ne pas le verbe en fin de phrase en français met ? Parce que ce l'usage est, et en conséquence les grammairiens que le verbe avant presque tous les compléments placé est expliquent. Ce ne pas une question de logique est. Si tu l'effort de une grammaire consulter fais, je sûr que tu la règle idoine trouveras suis.