# Emploi des pronoms toniques

Tags: pronoms

Considérons la phrase suivante :

> Tu as envoyé une lettre à son amie.

Je veux remplacer « une lettre » et « son amie » par les pronoms. Quel remplacement est correct ?

> 1. Tu lui en as envoyé une.
> 2. Tu l'as envoyée à elle.
> 3. T'en as envoyé à elle.

Si tous les trois sont corrects, quelle est différence ? Quelle variante est plus populaire dans le discours oral ?

Pourriez-vous me donner quelques commentaires sur les trois phrases ?

Merci d'avance !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace two nouns with pronouns?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7913/how-to-replace-two-nouns-with-pronouns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voici les possibilités :

> Tu la lui as envoyée. *(la lettre)*
>   Tu les lui as envoyées. *(les lettres)*
>   Tu lui en as envoyé. *(des lettres)*
>   Tu lui en as envoyé une. *(une lettre)*

On emploie *lui* plutôt que *à elle* en général. Sauf si on veut insister (souvent parce que l'interlocuteur s'est trompé) et dans ce cas il faut appuyer fort sur les mots à l'oral.

Autrement tes exemples étaient corrects. Chacun correspond à un déterminant différent pour *lettre* (pluriel ou singulier, défini ou indéfini). Aucun n'est plus populaire qu'un autre, ils ont des sens différents.

Comment: D'accord, maintenant je comprends. Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 1):

Bingo : ce n'est pas le bon "lui" :-)

Plus clairement, ici il ne convient pas d'utiliser un pronom tonique.

Voir ici par exemple : http://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/lui_a_lui.htm

------- ancienne réponse (à coté de la plaque)

Une remarque sur ta première phrase (effectivement la seule correcte, les deux autres me font penser à un interlocuteur anglo-saxon :-) : envoyé pas de E à la fin...

Pourquoi ?
Parce qu'avec l'auxiliaire avoir, l'accord du participe passé se fait uniquement avec le complément (d'objet direct) s'il est placé avant le verbe. Pour l'auxiliaire être pas de problème.

Exemples :

**un** courrier : "*je l'ai envoyé*"

**une** lettre : "*je l'ai envoyée*"

**des** objets : "*je les ai envoyés*"

**des** missives : "*je les ai envoyées*"

mais toujours : "*j'ai envoyé une lettre/un pli/des objets*"

et "*la femme était partie, l'homme est revenu, les enfants seront présents*"

Vive les complications de notre belle langue et bon courage !

Comment: Oui, oui, c'est vrai :-) Je vais corriger, merci ! Mais en fait, la question touche aux pronoms toniques. Je sais que il y a des verbes transitifs inderects qui n'acceptent pas le pronom personnel et s'emploient seulement avec le pronom tonique ("penser à toi" et "à lui" , mais pas "te penser" ou "lui penser"). Et aujourd'hui je me suis posé cette question: est-ce qu'il y a des verbes qui ne permettent pas s'employer avec le pronom tonique. Et pour être plus concret, pourquoi les deux dernières ne te semblent pas correctes ? C'est une affaire plutôt d'expérience ou de grammaire ?

Comment: Désolé, tombé à côté... mais je viens de réviser le pronom tonique :-)
Je pense que c'est grammatical (mais ça me "choque" aussi par expérience), à part pour l'appartenance (c'est à moi/à lui/à elle) ou effectivement pour insister (je te l'ai envoyé, à toi, pas à Michel) on n'utilise pas "à" devant ces pronoms. Pas encore trouvé de référence pour confirmer.
Mais d'autres (contre-)exemples : vouloir, aimer, regarder... on ne dit pas "je veux lui", "j'aime elle", "je regarde eux"

Comment: Hey, c'est vraiment le bingo ! Merci pour le lien, il y a une bonne explication sur ce site. Et le terme "verbes d'échange" - c'est ce que j'ai cherché toute la journée ! C'est assez simple et clair, je vais tester cette idée :-)

Comment: Et quant à ton commentaire, il ne faut pas d'exemples ou références pour confirmer quelque chose, j'ai bien compris ce que t'as voulu dire, mais ce qui m'interesse le plus ce sont les verbes qui demandent "à" devant le COI (pas "vouloir", "aimer", etc). (Je devrais mieux composer ma question !) Merci pour le lien encore une fois ! Pour résumer: si le verbe est un verbe "d'échange", on utilise le pronom personnel (ou "à + pronom tonique" pour insister, avec l'intonation convenue), sinon, c'est toujours "à + pronom tonique".