# In what cases does the indirect object pronoun come before the direct object pronoun?

Tags: pronoms

I've read that if the subject is third person singular, then the indirect object pronoun comes before the direct objects pronoun, instead of the normal rule where the DOP is before the IOP?

> For example:
>
> Je le leur lis.     -I read it to them
>
> Il **leur le** lit  -He reads it to them

Am I correct in believing this, if not does it occur with the DOP or IOP being 3rd person instead?

Comment: Probably relevant: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1738/the-order-of-direct-and-indirect-object-pronouns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the indirect pronoun is third person (lui or leur) then the indirect object pronoun comes **after** the DOP. Otherwise, the indirect object pronoun comes before the direct object pronoun.

> For example:
>
> Il me le donne (He gives it to me)
>
> Il le lui donne (He give it to him)

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is incorrect ; it should be *Il le leur lit*. I found a diagram that sums up the order of the pronouns in French : http://users.telenet.be/palm-mar/Taal_FRA_cod_coi.htm. As far as I know, it is correct.

This topic has probably been treated several times on this forum.