# Please explain the logic of "je te l’envoie"

Tags: pronoms

I'm confused by the sentence "je te l’envoie". As per the dictionary, it means "I will send it to you". Does it because the sequence of "te" & "le"?

I asked chatgpt, but it didn't give much explaination on it.

Please explaine it in detail.

Comment: It means "I'm **sending** it to you" [*envoyer*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/envoyer) is "send" not "give".  If your question is about pronoun objects order, you will find at least two (maybe more) questions already on this site. [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1738/358) and [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1738/358).

Comment: Are you confused by the tenses (present in French becomes future in English) or by the pronouns?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat  Thanks for your asking. I confused about the sequence of the pronouns and the linked question, in "None" comment, shows me the light.